# Could not locate a Flask application when creating a Docker Image

Tags: python, docker, flask, visual-studio-code

I hope someone can help me with this. The following error code comes up when I try and run docker run todolist-docker.

```
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

My folder directory is here:

```
Folder name: todoflaskappfinal
__pycache__
static
templates
venv
App.py
Dockerfile
requirements.txt
todo.db
ToDoList.db
```

within the todoflaskappfinal folder, I have a Dockerfile file:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.7.8

WORKDIR /tododocker

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

And within App.py, I've set up everything (I assume) correctly, obviously with more code between this.

```
#Website Configuration
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I've set FLASK_APP as App.py, made the virtual environment with venv, etc. When I type in `flask run` in the terminal it loads the website up correctly and displays it on 127.0.0.01. However, when I try and use the `docker build --tag todolist-docker` command and then `docker run todolist-docker`, the error message appears above. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error message suggests it's looking for `app.py` with a lowercase `a`, but you seem to have `App.py` with a capital `A`.  Does fixing the filename's case help?  Can you run this application in a native Python without Docker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is FLASK_APP defined in the docker container?  There's no ENV statement in the Dockerfile, and you didn't mention using docker's -e or --env command option.  Your container won't inherit your environment variables from the hosting environment.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.7.8

WORKDIR /tododocker

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
# Add this:
ENV FLASK_APP=App.py

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: Hey, sorry, now I'm really confused. What ENV statement do I need to add to the Dockerfile?

Comment: Try adding ENV FLASK_APP=App.py in your Dockerfile before the CMD line. Or use docker run -e FLASK_APP=App.py todolist-docker.  The latter overrides any environment variables already defined in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Hey, thank you so so much! This actually fixed everything, AND the error I was having with my sql-database.

Comment: You're welcome.  Utimately, consider some best practices for building Docker containers for Python code.  For example: https://www.docker.com/blog/containerized-python-development-part-1/.  What you're doing now will certainly work, but depending upon what's in your requirements.txt file, your image may consume a lot of space from files created under pip that you don't need at runtime.